# LG Optimus G fastboot not working

Tags: adb, fastboot

Alright, I have an LG Optimus G that I'm playing around with and trying to install ubuntu on. I'm following [this guide](http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) I've done everything up to the point where you enter this into the terminal:

```
$ adb reboot bootloader
```

Which just reboots the phone but not into the bootloader.

when I check for adb devices:

```
$ adb devices
devices attached 
LG-LS970-9c07c856   device
```

And when I run

```
$ fastboot devices
```

I get nothing. Any idea how to fix this so that it will reboot into the bootloader?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
adb reboot-bootloader
```

from the `adb` usage text

> `adb reboot [bootloader|recovery]` - reboots the device, optionally into the bootloader or recovery program
>   `adb reboot-bootloader` - reboots the device into the bootloader